# What is equivalent of php base_convert() in python 3?

Tags: python

I made an encoder function in PHP:

```php
function my_encoder($in){
    $out = base_convert($in,16,36);
return ($out);}

print(my_encoder(1234));
```

When I execute this function with `$in = 1234` the result is `3lg`.

I need to write an equivalent of this PHP function in Python and I don't know how.

Is there any Python function same as `base_convert()` in PHP?

Comment: Python has no built-in support for arbitrary base handling, it only has bespoke support for bases 2, 8, 10, and 16. If you want arbitrary base conversion you need to implement it yourself, both ways.

Comment: The built-in `int` function can parse integer literals in arbitrary bases. Converting an integer to a representation in an arbitrary base is not difficult to implement.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I don't know how to do that.